# Entity Framework - reusing associated extension methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to reuse an EF6 extension method with an associated entity (one to many relationship). Contrived example:

```
public class Parent 
{
   public string State { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public static ParentNamedScopes
{
   public static IQueryable<Parent> IsReady(this IQueryable<Parent> queryable) 
   {
      return queryable.Where(p => p.State == "Ready" || p.State == "New");
   }
}

// ...

var children = db.Children
   // my goal, but can't cast Parent to IQueryable<Parent>
   // ------------------v
   .Where(c => c.Parent.IsReady())
   .Where(c => c.Value == "Foobar");
```

I've seen examples of using AsQueryable() on associated collections in sub queries, but that isn't an options since Parent is a single record. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious and I apologize since my google foo has not turned up the answer today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to start your query with the Parents:

```
var children = db.Parents.IsReady()
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
    .Where(c => c.Value == "Foobar");
```

The idea that `IsReady` would convert an IQueryable seems a little off to me, though. If your use case gets more complex, you may need to change that to just give you an `Expression<Func<Parent, bool>>`, and use something like [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to manipulate your query to make it reusable:

```
Expression<Func<Parent, bool>> parentIsReady = ParentCriteria.IsReady();
var readyParents = db.Parents.Where(parentIsReady);
var childrenWithReadyParents = db.Children.AsExpandable()
   .Where(c => parentIsReady.Invoke(c.Parent))
   .Where(c => c.Value == "Foobar");
```

Comment: Thank you for the obvious answer I was missing. Another thanks for the new project to investigate.